# How to give a score to a negative value on Google Sheets? (formula edit needed)

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have negative values that I'd like to rank, however a while back I was only taught how to rank a range of positive values. Could you help me edit this one so that I can consider it in a *negative & positive range together*?

**=INDEX(IF($C7:$C="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP($BK7:BK*1, {0%, "0"; 0.01%, "1"; 5%, "2"; 10%, "3"; 15%, "4"; 20%, "5"; 25%, "6"; 30%, "7"; 35%, "8"}, 2, 1))))**

The column should fill up based on whether I've added a stock ticker or not, and will fill in a rank based on the result in the previous column (which you can see in the formula).

Comment: Google releases `BYROW()` and `XLOOKUP()`. You can omit old array approach and VLOOKUP. Share a sample workbook so that we can put formula for you.

Comment: Youwant to sort this range but has negative values `{0%, "0"; 0.01%, "1"; 5%, "2"; 10%, "3"; 15%, "4"; 20%, "5"; 25%, "6"; 30%, "7"; 35%, "8"}` ?

Comment: How would I be able to have both the negative and positive? Also I'm not sure how to implement the byrow and xlookup

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula

```
=SORT(A2:A, 1 , 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here

Comment: Hi @wheresjohnnywalker Given that you didn't provide an example, I made one up, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please share your desierd result.

Comment: apologies, I'll create a google sheet example and share it to you